# Reading from a URL always returns NULL

Tags: java, json, url, inputstream

So, I've tried a couple of solutions, but the result is always the same. I read from a randomly generated JSON file (www.json-generator.com), and the BufferedReader line always throws a NullPointerException. 
Here is my code:

```
public JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    URLConnection uc = new URL(JSONurl).openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream())
    String jsonText = readAll(in);
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
    return json;

}

//parse the json
public String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int counter;
    while((counter=rd.read())!=-1)
        sb.append((char)counter);
    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: There is some context missing because the second line contains ``new URL(JSONurl).openConnection()``, but the value of ``JSONurl`` is unclear. Also, the import statements for the mentioned classes would be useful.

Also, did you try to use a debugger to understand the place where an unexpected null value occurs?

Comment: [Here is the JSONUrl](http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceWCVbHMvC?indent=2)

 `import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;`

The exception occurs at the BufferedReader instantation line.

There are more import statements, but they are all related to Android Layouts and Views

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting by the way, this is my first time using StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks, the imports are useful. What I meant by "the value of ``JSONurl``" is the fact that in the constructor call ``new URL(JSONurl)``, the argument ``JSONurl`` must be a variable or field defined somewhere. This variable/field definition (and any statements that may influence its value) are missing.